# Embarcadero C++ Builder 10.3 не выдает подсказки по коду

Tags: radstudio, c++builder-xe

Указанную IDE установил с официального сайта. Trial версия (30 дней). При установке отметил галками C++ Builder x32 Win и C++ Builder x64 Win. У меня система Windows 7 x64 со всеми апдейтами. В настройках Builder'а, на вкладке  Properties -> Code Insight все галочки выставлены.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не выдаются подсказки (местный аналог IntelliSense, т.е. члены классов после ввода -> за именем экземпляра). Кратковременно мигают "песочные часики" и тут же пропадают. Ctrl + Space никак не реагирует.

Пожалуйста, подскажите, что ему еще нужно?

Comment: Старая бага, тянется еще со времен, когда разработка была в руках Borland. В 90% случаев помогает Build и перезапуск IDE

Comment: мне не помогло - не работает. что еще можно сделать?

Comment: @kwwsoft Возможно вам стоит задать новый вопрос, указав ссылку на текущий, но приведя свой собственный контекст.

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогло так:
В Code Insight убрал все галочки, сохранил. Потом опять все галочки выставил, сохранил и перезапустил программу. И всё заработало.

Answer (score -1):

Может кому поможет. У меня заработал code completion после включения, в настройках проекта, классического компилятора.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: мне не помогло - не работает. что еще можно сделать?

Comment: Пропатчить среду. https://community.idera.com/developer-tools/b/blog/posts/rad-studio-delphi-and-c-builder-10-3-2-list-of-patches И использовать классический компилятор

Answer (score -1):

Мне помог 2 вариант, в CodeInsight ( tools -> Option ) там данное поле, отключил все галочки, нажал сохранить, после обратно включил и что то начало работать!